# Regex Removing whitespace outside of double-quoted string

Tags: javascript, json

Good afternoon,

Today I was struggling with writing Regex in JavaScript, as I usually do. The idea is to use the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method in combination with a regular expression to remove all whitespace characters outside of double-quote pairs.

So far I've been able to find the pairs using `/(".*?")/g`, then ignoring those by turning it into `/(?=".*?")/g` then in a futile attempt at selecting all the whitespace outside of the capture group a turned it into `/\s+(?=".*?")/g`, this comes close.

```
string in:       this "string" should "give me "not so much trouble
_ as found:      this_"string"_should_"give me "not_so_much_trouble
after replace:   this"string"should"give me "notsomuchtrouble
```

My intend was to use this on JSON strings `{      "key":   "My value "    }` would then turn into `{"key":"My value"}`, hence the need to not touch the whitespace inside the double-quotes.

I'm sure this is doable with Regex I just simply can't find it, hopefully I've given enough information for someone with actual knowledge to help out. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

---

**yet another hurdle**

Second part is how do I ignore `\"` in the pattern for the `"`-pairs?

```
{      "key":   "he said \"how would I do this\" sadly?  "    }

becomes

{"key":"he said \"how would I do this\" sadly?  "}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression does a look head for the pattern quote any word and quote pattern as a capture group.  if it finds a space prior to the look ahead capture group than it replaces it with a space.

```
txt="""this "string" should "give me "not so much trouble"""

result=re.sub(r'\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', '', txt)
print(result)

this"string"should"give me "notsomuchtrouble
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, works like a charm (better than my own answer), but there's one more aspect I'd like to add. Can we ignore \" inside of "" groups? PS: I'll update my question as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is doable via regex.

Any reason you can't just:

```js
const theString = "{      \"key\":   \"My value \"    }";
const theCleanedUpString = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(theString));
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention this, but this question is mostly aimed at myself experimenting with Regex.

The solution that currently seems to work for me is `/(".*?")?(?:\s.*?)(".*?")?/g`

Breaking it down:

`(".*?")` creates a capture group to match everything between a pair of double quotes. (in-qoutes)

`(?:\s.*?)` matches a continuous sequence of whitespace but does not store it's group (whitespace)

`?` makes the previous group optional

`/g` any number of occurances within the string

combining them as `(in-quotes)?(whitespace)(in-quotes)?`

Then when replacing in js I can use the groups of all non-whitespace text:

```js
'{ "key"     :  "my value with spaces    
   and new-lines   "

   }'.replace(/(".*?")?(?:\s.*?)(".*?")?/g, '$1$2')
```

EDIT:

This however breaks when there are escaped quotes in the string

Answer (score 0):

If this just pertains to a JSON string and not source code.
To remove whitespace outside of quotes:

```js
var str = "{      \"key\":   \"he said \\\"how would I do this\\\" sadly?  \"    }";

console.log("Before:  " + str);

str = str.replace(/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*")|\\?\s+)/g, '$1$2', str);

console.log("After:   " + str);
```